# Dynamic routes next.js + nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

When opening page with route /markets/[coinId] on production through domain name, I'm getting error 404.

File:
_next/static/chunks/pages/market/%5BcoinId%5D-f8020cad1ec98b8a.js

When opening same page on production through IP address with port 3000, file was found without error.

I'm have problem with all pages with dynamic routes only in production with domain name.

Using nginx as proxy. Problem was getting after update all packages to last version.
Next.js deployed in docker, without docker have same problem.

Next 13.4.18
React 18.2.0

Nginx config:

```
location / {

    limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54008#issuecomment-1712672092
This solved my issue. By removing the trailing slash from proxy_pass. `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;`. May be you can give a try.

Comment: @SurajKV Thank you! I'm early solved by moved to _next folder to CDN and to used assetPrefix in next.config.js